# Reusable pageBlockSectionItem as custom component

Tags: visualforce-component

For clarity and maintenance reasons, I'd like to abstract away a commonly-used pageBlockSectionItem pattern in my VF pages to a component like this:

```
<apex:component >

  <apex:attribute name="controllerField"    required="true" type="Date"  description="Name of controller-referenced Opportunity sobject field"/>
  <apex:attribute name="label"          required="true" type="String" description="Label to use"/>
  <apex:attribute name="oppoId" required="true" type="String" />


  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(controllerField))}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!label}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!controllerField}" />
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!ISBLANK(controllerField)}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!label}"/>
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.Oppo_Upload_Document,$ObjectType.Opportunity,[id=oppoId])}" style="color: rgb(23,151,192)">
        Upload
        </apex:outputLink>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:component>
```

and reference multiple times in VF pages like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:outputField value="{!ow.o.blah}"/>
   <c:myComponent name="{!ow.o.foodate}" label="The foo date" oppoId="{!ow.o.id}"/>
   <apex:outputField value="{!ow.o.ugh}"/>
   <c:myComponent name="{!ow.o.bardate}" label="The bar date" oppoId="{!ow.o.id}"/>
   <!-- etc etc -->
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

But you can't define a pageBlockSectionItem as the top level apex component in a custom component. You get: 
**Save error:** `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem> tag must be between <apex:pageBlockSection>`

How does one get around this? I don't want the component to be a pageBlock or pageBlockSection. Simulating a pageBlockSectionItem as HTML defeats the ease of maintenance.

Comment: I subsequently realized that I could push the rendered= down into the apex:outputText and eliminate the pageBlockSectionItems from the component, makes the outer VF page a bit longer but achieves the goal